# Drupal 7 Batch Page Example

Tags: drupal, batch-file, drupal-7

I'm trying to setup a batch page for processing and I need an example. The example that's given in the Example module is within a form and I need a page that I can run independently of a form that will process batch requests.

For instance:

```
function mymodule_batch_2() {
 $operations[] = array('mymodule_onefunction','mymodule_anotherfunction') 
 $batch = array(
  'operations' => $operations, 
  'finished' => 'mymodule_finished',
  // We can define custom messages instead of the default ones. 
  'title' => t('Processing batch 2'), 
  'init_message' => t('Batch 2 is starting.'), 
  'progress_message' => t('Processed @current out of @total.'), 
  'error_message' => t('Batch 2 has encountered an error.'),
);
  batch_set($batch);
  batch_process('');
}
```

Where the batch function would call other functions in the form of $operations.

Comment: remove batch_process('');

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to give batch process an id to work from.   batch_process('mybatch')otherwise yourmexample is correct.   are you having a particular problem with this strategy?

Comment: My problem was that I was trying to call the entire batch process from a separate file that wasn't in the include path. I simply added the batch function to mymodule.module and parameter >> file << to call the remaining functions.

Comment: Alternatively, you can add a 'file' to your batch definition...  Be sure to build the full path to the include file using drupal_get_path

Comment: This answer is incorrect, since the first parameter to batch_process is the redirect URL, not an ID. See https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!form.inc/function/batch_process/7.x

Answer (score 2):

Here you can see my sample of batch relization with form that calls batch:

```
    function my_module_menu() {
      $items['admin/commerce/import'] = array(
        'title' => t('Import'),
        'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
        'page arguments' => array('my_module_settings_form'),
        'access arguments' => array('administer site settings'),
        'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,
      );
      return $items;
    }

    /**
     * Import form
     */
    function my_module_settings_form() {
      $form = array();
      $form['import'] = array(
        '#type' => 'fieldset',
        '#title' => t('Import'),
        '#collapsible' => TRUE,
        '#collapsed' => FALSE,
      );

      $form['import']['submit'] = array(
        '#type' => 'submit',
        '#value' => t('Import'),
      );
      return $form;
    }

    function my_module_settings_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {
      batch_my_module_import_start();
    }


    /**
     * Batch start function
     */
    function batch_my_module_import_start() {

      $batch = array(
        'title' => t('Import products'),
        'operations' => array(
          array('_batch_my_module_import', array()),
        ),
        'progress_message' => t('Import. Operation @current out of @total.'),
        'error_message' => t('Error!'),
        'finished' => 'my_module_batch_finished',
      );

      batch_set($batch);
    }

    /**
     * Import from 1C operation. Deletes Products
     */
    function _batch_my_module_import(&$context) {
      // Your iterms. In my case select all products
      $pids = db_select('commerce_product', 'p')
          ->fields('p', array('sku', 'product_id', 'title'))
          ->condition('p.type', 'product')
          ->execute()
          ->fetchAll();

      // Get Count of products
      if (empty($context['sandbox']['progress'])) {
        $context['sandbox']['progress'] = 0;
        $context['sandbox']['max'] = count($pids);
        watchdog('import', 'import products');
      }
      // Create Iteration variable
      if (empty($context['sandbox']['iteration'])) {
        $context['sandbox']['iteration'] = 0;
      }
      // Check for the end of cycle
      if ($context['sandbox']['iteration'] < $context['sandbox']['max']) {
        // Count of operation in one batch step
        $limit = 10;
        // Counts completed operations in one batch step
        $counter = 0;
        if ($context['sandbox']['progress'] != 0) {
          $context['sandbox']['iteration'] = $context['sandbox']['iteration'] + $limit;
        }
        // Loop all Product items in xml
        for ($i = $context['sandbox']['iteration']; $i < $context['sandbox']['max'] && $counter < $limit; $i++) {

          /* Loop items here */
          /* ... */
          /* ... */
          $context['results']['added']['products'][] = $product_item->title;


          // Update Progress
          $context['sandbox']['progress']++;
          $counter++;
          // Messages
          $context['message'] = t('Now processing product %name. Product %progress of %count', array('%name' => $product_item->title, '%progress' => $context['sandbox']['progress'], '%count' => $context['sandbox']['max']));
          $context['results']['processed'] = $context['sandbox']['progress'];
        }
      }

      if ($context['sandbox']['progress'] != $context['sandbox']['max']) {
        $context['finished'] = $context['sandbox']['progress'] / $context['sandbox']['max'];
      }
    }


/**
 * Finish of batch. Messagess
 */
function my_module_batch_finished($success, $results, $operations) {
  if ($success) {
    drupal_set_message(t('@count products added.', array('@count' => isset($results['added']) ? count($results['added']) : 0)));
  }
  else {
    $error_operation = reset($operations);
    drupal_set_message(t('An error occurred while processing @operation with arguments : @args', array('@operation' => $error_operation[0], '@args' => print_r($error_operation[0], TRUE))));
  }
  watchdog('import', 'import finished');
}
```

Comment: You hould push submit button. What do you mean autosubmit? You didn't mentioned it in question

Answer (score -1):

```
    function module_name_import_form_submit($form, $form_state) {
  // Check to make sure that the file was uploaded to the server properly
  $uri = db_query("SELECT uri FROM {file_managed} WHERE fid = :fid", array(
    ':fid' => $form_state['input']['import']['fid'],
  ))->fetchField();
  if(!empty($uri)) {
    if(file_exists(drupal_realpath($uri))) { 
      // Open the csv
      $handle = fopen(drupal_realpath($uri), "r");
      // Go through each row in the csv and run a function on it. In this case we are parsing by '|' (pipe) characters.
      // If you want commas are any other character, replace the pipe with it.
      while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 0, '|', '"')) !== FALSE) {
        $operations[] = array(
          'module_name_import_batch_processing',  // The function to run on each row
          array($data),  // The row in the csv
        );
      }

      // Once everything is gathered and ready to be processed... well... process it!
      $batch = array(
        'title' => t('Importing CSV...'),
        'operations' => $operations,  // Runs all of the queued processes from the while loop above.
        'finished' => 'module_name_import_finished', // Function to run when the import is successful
        'error_message' => t('The installation has encountered an error.'),
        'progress_message' => t('Imported @current of @total products.'),
      );
      batch_set($batch);
      fclose($handle);    
    }
  }
  else {
    drupal_set_message(t('There was an error uploading your file. Please contact a System administator.'), 'error');
  }
}

/**
 * This function runs the batch processing and creates nodes with then given information
 * @see
 * module_name_import_form_submit()
 */
function module_name_import_batch_processing($data) {
  // Lets make the variables more readable.
  $title = $data[0];
  $body = $data[1];
  $serial_num = $data[2];
  // Find out if the node already exists by looking up its serial number. Each serial number should be unique. You can use whatever you want.
  $nid = db_query("SELECT DISTINCT n.nid FROM {node} n " . 
    "INNER JOIN {field_data_field_serial_number} s ON s.revision_id = n.vid AND s.entity_id = n.nid " .
    "WHERE field_serial_number_value = :serial", array(
      ':serial' => $serial_num,
    ))->fetchField();
  if(!empty($nid)) {
    // The node exists! Load it.
    $node = node_load($nid);

    // Change the values. No need to update the serial number though.
    $node->title = $title;
    $node->body['und'][0]['value'] = $body;
    $node->body['und'][0]['safe_value'] = check_plain($body);
    node_save($node);
  }
  else {
    // The node does not exist! Create it.
    global $user;
    $node = new StdClass();
    $node->type = 'page'; // Choose your type
    $node->status = 1; // Sets to published automatically, 0 will be unpublished
    $node->title = $title;
    $node->uid = $user->uid;        
    $node->body['und'][0]['value'] = $body;
    $node->body['und'][0]['safe_value'] = check_plain($body);
    $node->language = 'und';

    $node->field_serial_number['und'][0]['value'] = $serial_num;
    $node->field_serial_number['und'][0]['safe_value'] = check_plain($serial_num);
    node_save($node);
  }
}

/**
 * This function runs when the batch processing is complete
 *
 * @see
 * module_name_import_form_submit()
 */
function module_name_import_finished() {
    drupal_set_message(t('Import Completed Successfully'));
}
```

Comment: You should add more information and/or description on how work and how this answer the question so that others can understand it easily without asking for more detail. Anyway, welcome to StackOverflow :)